# How to get logarithmic values for x-axis to an histogram

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, audio

This is math/javascript one. So, in javascript I'm doing a histogram using divs for the bars and x-spacing them using left margin property. So I want this spacing to be scaled in a logarithmic way.

Not like this:
bar----bar----bar----bar----bar----bar

But something like this:
bar---------bar------bar----bar--bar-bar

Note that the total number of divs (**bars** variable) may change (not at runtime).
I'm having trouble to find that **x** logarithmic values, for each i from 0 to **bars**, with proper margin values related to 100% containerDiv width.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
   $("<div/>").css("left", i * x  + "%").appendTo(containerDiv);
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So can't you just use `Math.log` (or `Math.log10`)? They will return small numbers not suitable for % values, so maybe add a scaling multiplier. `.css("left", (Math.log(i) * scale) + "%")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Set some `maxLeft` variable, then you can a function like this

```
const maxLeft = 100;
f = (i) => maxWidth * Math.log(i+1) / Math.log(bars.length)
```

Or if you are in older JavaScript versions

```
function (i) {
    var maxLeft = 100;
    return maxLeft * Math.log(i+1) / Math.log(bars.length)
}
```